# Nagios Auto Rescheduling Feature Default Values Wrong?

Tags: nagios

I am trying to understand how the auto rescheduling logic is supposed to work.
The recommended values in nagios.cfg are:

```
auto_reschedule_checks=1
auto_rescheduling_interval=30
auto_rescheduling_window=45
```

Supposedly this is after they realized the default values (same as above but with window=180) had the potential to have checks that never actually get executed (See https://support.nagios.com/kb/print-19.html).
But.. How are these new values any different?
How I understand it, every 30sec, it takes the next 45sec of checks, finds checks that overlap, and reschedules those evenly across the 45sec.
Isnt it possible for a check to indefinitely get rescheduled into that last 15 seconds of the 45sec window?
Am I missing something? Do rescheduled checks get an elevated priority so they arent rescheduled again? Reading through the code, it doesnt appear they are given any special treatment.

Seems to me that the only way to prevent that is for the interval and window to be the same.
Which means maybe a couple checks occurring right at each 30sec transition may go unnoticed,
but Id rather that than what I am presuming the behavior is with the "recommended" interval=30sec , window=45sec.

Any insights would be helpful!

Comment: I suggest you read the link you posted more carefully. It’s about a bug affecting 4.0.8 and the config changes are suggested as a way to work around that bug. The latest release is 4.4.9, do you have reason to believe the bug is still present?

Comment: Also the way these settings work is described here https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/configmain.html

Comment: @pzkpfw Thanks for the response.  
I have not seen evidence of the bug, no. I arrive at my confusion after reading the documentation and the scheduling code in Core. And it appears to me it's still possible for a service to continuously get rescheduled to the final 15min of the upcoming 45sec window (since the check for overlaps gets re-run every 30sec).

What I gather from the code is, it takes all upcoming checks that overlap another check, stick them in a queue, and divide them out evenly over the 45sec.

Comment: ...so my imagined edge case is: Check A is picked as a candidate to reschedule. It gets rescheduled to the last 15sec of the window. During the next rescheduling event 30sec later, that 15sec becomes the first 15sec of this next window. If that is a busy 15sec full of overlaps, and the rest of the window is relatively empty, those overlappers will be the bulk of whats laid out over the entire window, all the way out to the end (something that was originally scheduled for 14sec in is now  at 43sec after rescheduling, for example).. and so what if that cycle continued?